# Garbage Collection Java Classes

Tags: java, garbage-collection

In the following code, is the object rectangle possible to be destroyed by the garbage collector?

```
...
 Point point = new Point(2,4);
 Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle (point, 20, 20);
 point = null;
...
```

I believe it is rational that both point and rectangle be destroyed by the garbage collector because rectangle references point which is nullified.

Comment: If the rentangle is still using, nothing to be collected!

Comment: The `Rectangle` instance **does not** reference `point` -- it references the object that `point` referred to at the line where you instantiate `Rectangle`. The variable `point` is passed by value, so whatever you do to the var afterwards cannot have any effect on the `Rectangle` instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Object becomes eligible for Garbage collection or GC if its not reachable from any live threads or any static refrences -  you can say that an object becomes eligible for garbage collection if its all references are null.  Also, read up on reference types (strong, weak, soft & phantom).

Comment: So nothing will be collected since after the point=null the object point still has a reference.

Answer (score 1):

Neither object can be collected because `rectangle` refers to the Rectangle and it refers to the Point object. The fact `point` not longer refers to anything doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what the constructor for Rectangle does. It can either store a reference to the point object or copy its values.

In the first case, neither object will be GCed. In the second case, only Point will be GCed.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give quite enough of an example to say.  They will both be eligible for GC as soon as they go out of scope, which is the nearest set of braces that includes the declaration.

Assuming that rectangle has a field of type Point inside and it stores the point you pass it:

```
{
 Point point = new Point(2,4);
 Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle (point, 20, 20);
 point = null;
 //No GC yet!
}
//Now they can be GC'd
```

Setting the point reference to null has nothing to do with this really.  The GC will identify "circular" references and collect both objects if nothing else has a reference.  Setting your point variable to null *does not* nullify the point inside of rectangle if you stored a copy of it!  `point = null;` sets the value of that pointer to null, it does not change the object it used to point to!